# Do not expose HTTP 302 redirect by HTTP reverse proxy - handle it internally

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, http, redirect

I'm creating a Facebook client for a very limited device - its web browser (ANT Galio) does not handle properly HTTP302 for source of images.

My UC looks like this - in web application markup profile images are placed in the manner:

> `<img src="http://reverseproxyfqdn/graph.facebook.com/profileId/picture/" />`

When proxy asks for **graph.facebook.com/profileId/picture/** it gets HTTP 302 redirect to different address, for example **fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/someUrl**. This response is reverse proxied to web browser with Location header changed to **reverseproxyfqdn/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/someUrl**. All the web browsers I've tested handle it properly, but not ANT Galio. I need to return image got from **fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/someUrl** directly as a response to **reverseproxyfqdn/graph.facebook.com/profileId/picture/** - so do not expose the whole HTTP 302 redirect story to the web browser.

Does anyone know how to do it in Nginx or Apache 2.2? I would like to avoid creating a special PHP/Perl/Java app for this and achieve it by HTTP server configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider the [proxy_redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect) directive which might help you dealing with this problem.

Comment: I'm using this directive but this is not what I want. I do not want HTTP server to respond to the browser with modified HTTP 302 (this is what proxy_redirect@nginx or PrxyReverse@Apache does). I want it to send a file which is in Location header.

Comment: Okay, I understood what you want to do. Apparently this is not possible. Nginx is not designed to be used as a forward proxy like Squid (e.g proxy acts as a HTTP client), but only as a reverse proxy.

Comment: However I am curious to know (and I expect) if there is a trick to bypass this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't send the `graph.facebook.com/.../picture/...` URLs to the browser in the first place. Instead, resolve them yourself on the server side while you're creating the HTML pages and insert the CDN URLs in their place.