# HTTP reverse proxy redirect internally

Tags: redirect, reverse-proxy

To me, this seems like a simple scenario:

- Client makes request to reverse proxy at server `X` (`http://proxy.example.com`)
- Server `X` forwards request to backend server `Y` (`http://internal1.example.com:8000`)
- Backend server `Y` responds with `3xx` redirect to another backend server `Z` (`http://internal2.example.com:8000`)
- Proxy server `X` **intercepts** the 3xx redirect and makes the request again to backend server `Z`. *It does not return the 3xx redirect back to the client.*
- Proxy server `X` responds to the client with the result of the redirected request from backend server `Z`.

I need this because some clients do not seem to handle the redirection (especially when doing PUT), so I would like the redirection to happen invisibly and internally on the proxy server. (I am actually running a WebDAV server on the backend, so my clients are Cyberduck, Nautilus, OSX Finder, etc).

I've searched a huge amount for an existing answer to this, but had no luck ([this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/369932/do-not-expose-http-302-redirect-by-http-reverse-proxy-handle-it-internally) is basically what I want, but there are no satisfactory answers and it's been inactive for a year. Hopefully things have changed since then).

I would like to use an existing soluion for this if possible. Is it possible with Apache/Nginx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after much more googling, and a chat with the apache guys on IRC, it seems to be impossible with apache. So I took a look at nginx, and managed to find a solution using `X-Accel-Redirect` with a configuration like the one at the end of this answer.

See the relevant blog posts:

- http://kovyrin.net/2010/07/24/nginx-fu-x-accel-redirect-remote/
- http://kovyrin.net/2006/11/01/nginx-x-accel-redirect-php-rails/

  ```
  server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  example.com;

      location / {
          proxy_pass         http://localhost:8000/;
          proxy_redirect     http://localhost:8001   http://$host:8001;

          proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
          proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }

      # Proxy download 
      location ~* ^/internal_redirect/(.*?)/(.*) {
          # Do not allow people to mess with this location directly
          # Only internal redirects are allowed
          internal;

          # Location-specific logging
          access_log internal_redirect.access.log main;
          error_log  internal_redirect.error.log  debug;

          # Extract download url from the request
          set $download_uri  $2;
          set $download_host $1;

          # Compose download url
          set $download_url http://$download_host/$download_uri?$args;

          # Set download request headers
          proxy_set_header Host $download_host;
          proxy_set_header Authorization '';

          # The next two lines could be used if your storage 
          # backend does not support Content-Disposition 
          # headers used to specify file name browsers use 
          # when save content to the disk
          # proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;
          # add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$args"';

          # Do not touch local disks when proxying 
          # content to clients
          proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

          # Download the file and send it to client
          # This is where the magic happens
          proxy_pass $download_url;
      }
  }
  ```